# How can I prevent duplication on chunks when I use dynamic imports?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chunks, code-splitting, dynamic-import

I will contextualize my question with some example code. I created a new project using CRA (not ejected).

I have this on **App.js**:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import DropDown from "./components/DropDown";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="picker">
      <h1>Pick a letter</h1>
      <DropDown />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see it just is a title with a DropDown Component.

This is **DropdownComponent.js**:

```
import React, { useState, lazy, Suspense } from "react";

const A = lazy(() => import("./A.js"));
const B = lazy(() => import("./B.js"));
const C = lazy(() => import("./C.js"));

const DropDown = () => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState("");

  const content =
    option === "A" ? (
      <Suspense fallback="loading A...">
        <A />
      </Suspense>
    ) : option === "B" ? (
      <Suspense fallback="loading B...">
        <B />
      </Suspense>
    ) : option === "C" ? (
      <Suspense fallback="loading C...">
        <C />
      </Suspense>
    ) : (
      "No choice yet"
    );

  const pickOption = (e) => {
    setOption(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <select name="letters" id="letters" onChange={pickOption}>
        <option value="" disabled selected>
          Select your option
        </option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
      </select>
      {content}
    </>
  );
};

export default DropDown;
```

Here basically I imported  A, B, and C components using *dynamic imports* and then depending on what you choose on the selector it shows the corresponding component (A, B, and C).

Now on each letter components, I imported (just for this exercise) a random image component called  **react-random-image** like this:
(all letter components are  the  same so I will show just the first one)

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "react-random-image";

const A = () => (
  <>
    <p>This is A component</p>
    <Image width={200} height={200} />
  </>
);

export default A;
```

So if I build this project and check the chunks with **webpack-bundle-analyzer** we found that there are the 3 chunks generated with dynamic imports but if you noticed **react-random-image** is present on each chunk!

chunks duplicated on 3 chunks:

[image: chunks duplicated on 3 chunks]

So my question is if there is some way to prevent that kind of duplication when you use dynamic import like this example.

Comment: HI glober! Did you try passing the image down through props to each component and just having the single import in the `App.js` ?

Comment: Thanks, @WistonCoronell your solution does the work! it's really easy to implement and without to eject CRA nor add something like CRACO to the project.

I think that webpack should be smart enough to prevent duplicated libraries with dynamic imports but anyway this solution it's really helpful at the moment.